# Sorting/formatting Counter output

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I'm trying to sort the output of Counter by value size. Current code outputs them in a seemingly random order

```
from collections import Counter
query_list = list()

for line in contents:
      if not line.startswith("#"):
            columns = line.split()
            query = str(columns[9])
            query_list.append(query)

queries = Counter(query_list)
for key, value in queries.items():
    print(value,key)
```

Current output looks like the following:

```
36 key_a
24 key_b
18 key_c
97 key_d
99 key_f
```

Ideally, output would be sorted largest to smallest, like so:

```
99 key_f
97 key_d
36 key_a
24 key_b
18 key_c
```

Using `sorted` gives a type error as you would expect

```
---> 12     print(sorted(value,key))
     13 
     14 

TypeError: sorted expected 1 arguments, got 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `most_common()` method of `Counter` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)):

```
from collections import Counter

values = {'key_a': 36,
'key_b': 24,
'key_c': 18,
'key_d': 97,
'key_f': 99}

c = Counter(values)

for key, count in c.most_common():
    print(count, key)
```

Prints:

```
99 key_f
97 key_d
36 key_a
24 key_b
18 key_c
```

EDIT: If you want to use `sorted()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for key, count in sorted(c.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(count, key)
```